# How to make variable to be a literal string

Tags: c++

Code as below:

```
FILE *sfp;
....

void test(char *s, ...)
{
  va_list ap;
  va_start(ap, s);
  vfprintf(sfp, s, ap);
  fflush(sfp);
  va_end(ap);
}
```

below compile error reported:

```
error: format string is not a string literal [-Werror,-Wformat-nonliteral]
  vfprintf(sfp, s, ap);
```

How to fix this error?

Comment: you cannot convert variable into string literal

Comment: [Can't duplicate](https://ideone.com/sSoulU).

Comment: @RSahu Looks like [only clang](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/897f3a8dac4b6a9a) warns in this situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A variable is never a string literal.  A string literal is a sequence of characters surrounded by double quote marks (i.e. `"foo"`).

The purpose of that warning is to warn you that the compiler cannot confirm that the types of the parameters given to `vfptrintf` match the format string.  To get rid of that warning, you will need to either

1. Pass a literal format string to `vfprintf` (i.e. `vfprintf(sfp, "%d\n", ap)`)
2. Disable (or rather, don't enable) that warning and accept that the compiler cannot warn you if your arguments don't match the format specifier.
3. Add the `format` attribute to your function declaration (thanks to @chris in the comments):

i.e.

```
__attribute__((format(printf, 2, 3)))
void test(FILE* sfp, const char *s, ...)
{
    //...
}
```

Or with the standardized C++11 attribute syntax:

```
[[gnu::format(printf, 2, 3)]]
void test(FILE* sfp, const char *s, ...)
{
    //...
}
```

Note that that last option is not a standard C++ attribute, and therefore will not work on all compilers.  You may need something else to appease MSVC for example.  By the standard, compilers should ignore unknown attributes if you use the C++11 syntax, but they may still emit a warning about it, putting you right back in the same situation you're in now.

You will also still provoke a warning if `test` is called with a second argument that is not itself a string literal.

---

As a side note, it doesn't look like clang can check the argument types of the `va_list` `printf` functions anyway, so -Wformat-nonliteral isn't actually helpful in this case.  GCC does not emit this warning, likely for that exact reason.

Comment: It seems the error goes away if you tell Clang the parameter is a format string via `__attribute__((format(printf, 2, 3)))`

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out @chris.  Added it to the answer.

Comment: Not sure why I didn't try this, but the better option is probably `[[gnu::format(printf, 2, 3)]]`. If a compiler can't understand it, the compiler has to ignore it.